# Generating samples from binomial distribution using fewest coin tosses

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

We can generate samples from the binomial distribution B~(n,p) where p = 1/2 by tossing a fair coin n times and counting the number of times it comes up heads. I think the expected number of coin tosses required to generate each sample here is n; can any another method generate the samples using fewer coin tosses on average?

Comment: I don't understand what this means.  What do you intend by "the expected number of tosses required to generate each sample?"  Do you mean each outcome -- $h$ heads, $n-h$ tails?  You have to toss $n$ coins to generate one outcome, don't you?  Do you mean the expected number of experiments necessary so that each outcome occurs at least once?  Surely this is far more than $n,$ particularly since there are $n+1$ different outcomes.  Please add more details.

Comment: Is your question "Can I generate samples from a Binomial[n,1/2] distribution without having to flip n fair coins?"